# Google App Engine doesn't execute print statements

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I just added some print statements to see what arguments are actually being passed to the methods, but nothing is ever printed to the console. For instance, I have:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getListings")
    public List<Listing> getListings() {
        System.out.println("Getting listings");
        return ofy().load().type(Listing.class).list();
    }
```

If I make a change to the return statement (e.g. adding a filter), I can see the changes, but it never prints anything. Does anybody know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use https://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/  Works with objectify just fine.

This way client code and server code can use the same logging statements. [That's useful since if I'm offline and can't call the server, I'll try handling stuff locally].  So it'll work fine in shared code and objectify objects that are being sent to/from the client/server.

See https://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/wiki/GettingStarted but basically the steps are:

1) configure *.gwt.xml

```
  <!-- For development, a default of `DEBUG` is recommended -->
  <inherits name="com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.gwt-log-DEBUG" />
```

2) import to your java code

```
import com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.client.Log;
```

3) log

```
Log.debug("Getting listings");
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out` does not write to the App Engine logs. `System.err` does.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.logging`. It's usually helpful to use a facade for j.u.l like http://www.slf4j.org/

In server-side programming, console print statements are generally not used.